# Bitcoind blockchain download loop

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, linux

I downloaded and setup the bitcoind
and by using the command to check the progress of the download it shows like it gets to 25k~ and then starts over back from 0 and so it continues in a handless loop.
Here it is a screenshot that show what im talking about
http://prntscr.com/eoeuhe
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: By the way, you can omit -rpcuser and -rpcpassword if it's in your bitcoin.conf. bitcoin-cli knows how to read bitcoin.conf for that.

Comment: I have tried to omit them but even if those are in my bitcoin.conf it says like I have to put them

Comment: Huh, that's odd.

Comment: Have you looked in the `debug.log` file? What version of bitcoind is this?

Comment: How much free memory does the system have? It may be running out of memory at flush time, and then needing to start over.

Comment: it starts going then it says "couldn't connect to server uknown (code -1) make sure server is running and you are connecting to the correct rpc port and starts over. Im looking to the debug.log but can't find anything.. will try to kill all the processes and wait for the client to finish downloading

Comment: freeing some memory it let me get to 150k~ then it crashes again even if it uses only 50~% Mem and 18~% cpu
kib mem 499056 total, 5796 free, 266392 used 226868 buff/mem

Comment: For everybody that wants to run bitcoind on a server, be assured you need 150 GB of disk space.
That's absurd.
Also 300-500~ gb od bandwith monthly.

Comment: Neither of these two blanket statements is correct. :) Please look into [pruning](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37496/5406) and [blocksonly](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/45845/5406).